# How to make a compatible application with CQtDeployer for any version of Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qt5, compatibility

I deployed my Qt Gui application with CQtDeployer on Ubuntu 18.04.
But, I can't run it on Ubuntu 16.04 / Ubuntu 14.04.
It has an error on version.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: do you have zlib installed? try installing it with this command `sudo apt install zlib1g`

Answer (score 0):

### Just build and deploy your application on ubuntu 14.04

Your distribution not run because you build and deploy application on OS that has new version of (libc/libz) library.

So, If you want to create distribution that will be works correctly on all versions of your OS then you need to build and deploy application must early OS version.

**Example**

Application that was built on ubuntu 16.04 will be works great on ubuntu 18.04 , 20.04 and may be 22.04

But not 14.04 because minimum required libc level is some as on ubuntu 16.04.

### How to get cqdeployer on ubuntu 14.04

Install from snap store:

```
sudo snap install cqtdeployer 
sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:process-control
sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:removable-media
sudo snap connect cqtdeployer:system-backup
```

### And NOTE

The ubuntu 14.04 too  old. So i recommend to drop support of ubuntu 14.04.
User Ubuntu 16.04 as main build machine.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. Then, which version of QtCreator is better to use? It is irrelevant or is the old version of Qt better?

Comment: I tried to install cqtdeployer on ubuntu 14.04.
But, plugins of cqtdeployer were not installed properly.
During deploying, I got error "error: snap "cqtdeployer" has no plug named "system-backup".

Comment: About qt and qt creator it is irrelevant. You should build your application using native build tools like a gcc. I recommend create a separate virtual machine for build or lxd container.